# how to delete sub doc only on expire using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problem deleting subdocument from collection 1, when document in collection 2 is expire.

I have cart schema like below.

```
var cartSchema = new schema({
    userName    : {type: String, default: null},
    total       : {type: Number, default: 0},
    qty         : {type: Number, default: 0},
    productId   : {type: String, default: null},
    createdAt   : {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 7200} // expired in 2 hours
});
```

and here I have schema which save object `carted` related to `cartSchema`

```
var merchantSchema = new schema({
    seller          : String,
    address         : String,
    email           : String,
    products        : [
       {
          title         : String,
          ingredients   : String,
          qty           : Number,
          carted        : [
              {
                  qty       : Number, 
                  cartId    : String, 
                  createdAt : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
              }
       }
    ],

});
```

since `expireAt` query runs automatically, I don't know how to delete automatically carted object when cart expired and deleted.

when cart in `cartSchema` with `id 123` expired and deleted, so cart in carted object with `id 123` will also be deleted.

if I add `expires` property in `merchantSchema createdAt : {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 7200}`, it will delete whole document.

Comment: The `"expires"` option in mongoose schema's actually creates a [TTL](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/) index. That process removes "documents" from the "collection" rather than "array members" from the "document". There is unfortunately no such built in action for array entry removal in MongoDB. Also since there is no actualy record that says *"this document _id was deleted"*, you could not even track in the oplog. Doing this would require a separate periodic process to run. Probably a bit broad an explanation for a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: ok thanks, so i have to manually delete the sub document.

Comment: Well it won't be handled by TTL expiry, and if you tried you would end up deleting the whole document. Even pulling from the array is not a straigtforward process, since you have nested `"carted"` within the `"products"` array. Nested arrays are often not a great idea for MongoDB as is explained in the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `TTL index` to delete sub-document.

One workaround could be done through change your data schema through [`population`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) as below

```
var merchantSchema = new schema({
    seller          : String,
    address         : String,
    email           : String,
    products        : [productSchema],
});

var Merchant = mongoose.model('Merchant', merchantSchema);

var productSchema = new Schema({
    title         : String,
    ingredients   : String,
    qty           : Number
});

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

var cartSchema = new schema({
    userName    : {type: String, default: null},
    total       : {type: Number, default: 0},
    qty         : {type: Number, default: 0},
    productId   : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
    createdAt   : {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 7200} // expired in 2 hours
});
```

Then the `createdAt` expires, then the `cart` document will be deleted, and there is no cart information related to `product` document.

Comment: yes, at lasti i change the schema. i think its better using this schema.